# How to create this linear fading opacity effect in flutter for android?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Hi there I am new to flutter and I want to create this design but I am confused on how to create this linear opacity shadow effect overlay for this text as marked in the image

And what is the name of this icon that I have circled?[image: The design I want to create in flutter]

Comment: Maybe you want this https://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/YzwaJeY

Comment: Thank you very much... You solved my problem

Comment: And I also asked about thos icons

Answer (score 5):

You could use a CustomPainter with a LinearGradient:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePageState createState() => MyHomePageState();
}

class MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: CustomPaint(
        foregroundPainter: FadingEffect(),
        //child gets the fading effect
        child: Text(
            'Test text',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FadingEffect extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Rect rect = Rect.fromPoints(Offset(0, 0), Offset(size.width, size.height));
    LinearGradient lg = LinearGradient(
        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        colors: [
          //create 2 white colors, one transparent
          Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
          Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
        ]);
    Paint paint = Paint()..shader = lg.createShader(rect);
    canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(FadingEffect linePainter) => false;
}
```

Comment: Thank u very much for your answer... You are awesome....

Answer (score 4):

You can use a ShaderMask to achieve that, below I have provided an example that can either blur out vertical edges or horizontal edges.

```
class FadedEdges extends StatelessWidget {
  const FadedEdges(
      {Key? key,
      required this.child,
      this.colors,
      this.stops,
      this.isHorizontal = false})
      : super(key: key);
  final Widget child;
  final List<Color>? colors;
  final List<double>? stops;
  final bool isHorizontal;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ShaderMask(
            blendMode: BlendMode.dstOut,
            shaderCallback: (Rect rect) => LinearGradient(
                    colors: colors ??
                        [
                          Colors.white.withOpacity(0.80),
                          Colors.transparent,
                          Colors.transparent,
                          Colors.white.withOpacity(0.80)
                        ],
                    stops: stops ?? const [0.1, 0.15, 0.85, 1.0],
                    begin: !isHorizontal
                        ? Alignment.topCenter
                        : Alignment.centerLeft,
                    end: !isHorizontal
                        ? Alignment.bottomCenter
                        : Alignment.centerRight)
                .createShader(rect),
            child: child)
        ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Container has Gradient too ... so Easy to use check this code please ... and set color to `colors.Transparent`

```
    Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [Colors.green,Colors.red],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
              )
          ),
        )
```

Comment: This is the simplest implementation but it is applied behind the child of container. Ie. it doesn't affect the containers child widget.